# Removing padding at end of rust vector?

Tags: rust

I have gotten this neat way of padding vector messages, such that I can know that they will be the same length

```
let len = 20;
let mut msg = vec![1, 23, 34];
msg.resize(len, 0);
println!("msg {:?}", msg);
```

Nice, this pads a lot of zeros to any message, running this code will give me:

```
msg [1, 23, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But let's say I send this message over some connection, and the other party receives it at their end.
How do I take a vector like this, and strip off all the 0's in the end?

Notice that the length of the original message may be of variable length, but always less than 20

Another thing that could work for me, is to have all the padding at the beginning of the vector, doing something like this:

```
let len = 20;
let msg = vec![1, 23, 34];
let mut  payload = vec![0;len-msg.len()];
payload.extend(&msg);
println!("msg {:?}", payload);
```

And then just removing, all the preleading zero's.

Comment: What if the `msg` ends with a `0`? Should that be stripped as well? Consider using the first element of the message to send the length of `msg`, then the padding could be removed easily.

Comment: You have to pass in the actual length information separately, (at which point you might as well make the entire value variable-size imo). A somewhat cheaper way would be to prefix the item with its padding byte, but this requires much more client-side complexity. Alternatively, update your protocol such that your padding value is *manifestly invalid* (that is why fixed-size strings in C generally use the nul byte).

Comment: yes, I thought of either doing that, or having a 1 at the end of every message, indicating thta padding begins there. The issue with having a number at the start is that I already have one indicator at the beginning

Comment: Removing all the "preleading zero's" has the same problem, you don't know if the message started with zeros or not. What is the problem if you have two indicators at the beginning?

Comment: the good thing about the preleading zeros is that my messages always have a non-zero number at the start, since they start with message identifiers, which are never 0

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above, probably changing your protocol to include the length of the message is cleaner.

But here would be the solution to remove padding in front of the message (if the message doesn't start with zeros):

```rust
let msg: Vec<_> = payload.into_iter().skip_while(|x| *x == 0).collect();
```

Note that this allocates a new `Vec` for your msg, probably you could use the iterator directly.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab56bbc284cddc0460cb44fa027a8c9a)

Comment: You could also `.count()` instead of `.collect()` and this would give you the starting index, then you can take the slice `&payload[index..]` as the message.